# How to get a string from a line in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have this line of strings:

```
String line = "GET /MyFile.extension  HTTP/1.1\n\n"
```

I want to get only the the file name **MyFile.extension** string, I tried this but the problem the HTTP version could change.

```
String fileName = line.replace("GET /", "");
fileName = fileName.replace(" HTTP/1.1", "");
```

This doesn't work too:

```
string fileName = line.indexOf("MyFile.extension");
```

I don't know the file Name too, it could be any file, It there a way to get that file between the strings "GET/" and "HTTP/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple do this: `line.split(" ")[1].substring(1)`

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String line = "GET /MyFile.extension  HTTP/1.1\n\n";
    System.out.println(line.split(" ")[1].substring(1));
}
```

Output:

```
MyFile.extension
```

Comment: Thaanks! you are the best!!

Comment: Your Welcome! Request you to accept the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
       String line = "GET /MyFile.extension  HTTP/1.1\n\n";

       // To find the index of "/"
       int start = line.indexOf("/");

       // To find the index of space from int start which I got from the line above
       int end = line.indexOf(" ", start);

       // To extract the given string from the start+1 index to the end index 
       String s = line.substring(start+1, end);

       System.out.println(s);       
    }
```

Output :

```
MyFile.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression to get you in the inner value

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("GET (.*?) HTTP/1.1")
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // MyFile.extension
}
```